# Flutter Paginated Data Table: Filter RowData

Tags: flutter, dart, paginateddatatable

I have been using the PaginatedDataTable widget in flutter and am looking to add a search bar to filter down the rows based on the input

However there is no clear way to do this; most tutorials only show sorting the columns.

When I modify the RowData object that's passed into the source input of the table nothing happens.

Does anyone have any tips on what I'm missing?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: use advanced_datatable
https://pub.dev/packages/advanced_datatable

Comment: So it's not possible with the paginated table widget I'm using at all?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you are missing a [notifyListeners](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/foundation/ChangeNotifier/notifyListeners.html) after changing the data source?

> Call this method whenever the object changes, to notify any clients the object may have changed. Listeners that are added during this iteration will not be visited. Listeners that are removed during this iteration will not be visited after they are removed.